# If $G'=G$, and suppose $N_G(P)$ is solvable for $P\subseteq G$, show that $ G$ is simple.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Given a finite nontrivial group $G$, Suppose $N_G(P)$ is solvable for every nontrivial $P\subseteq G$ of prime power order. If $G'=G$, (where $G'$ is the derived subgroup) show that $G$ is simple.

I understand the pieces of information given in the problem but how to put them together to make an argument is challenging to me. I will appreciate any help.

I am thinking that, if I start by assuming $G$ is not simple and that there exists a normal nontrivial subgroup $ N\triangleleft G$.

And if  I can show that the commutator subgroup $G'=1$ then since $G'=G$ I get a contradiction to the nontriviality assumption of the group.

Is this a good way to go?  How should I view it?
 Thanks

Comment: Choose $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(N)$ for some prime $p$ dividing $N$. Then by the Frattini Argument $G = NN_G(P)$ and $G/N \cong N_G(P)/N_N(P)$. Now use the facts that $N_G(P)$ is solvable and $G'=G$ to deduce that $G=N$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, thank you. but why is $G/N=N_G(P)/N_N(P)$.?

Comment: That's the second isomorphism theorem